# How should I read the specifications on my PSU?

Tags: graphics-card, power-supply

I want to get an AMD Radeon HD 6670 for my PC but I do not know if my PSU is good enough for it, because there is nothing written on it about the power. I have provided a photo of it below.

How can I determine if I will be able to use that card with this PSU?

[image: Picture of PSU]

Comment: I would imagine based on your image that it's 450W (it has a red line through it, which is normally used as indication of specification when dealing with generic labels for multiple versions of a product).

Comment: Unsure, but it is a 450W power supply and you can use a website like the [eXtreme Power Supply Calculator](http://extreme.outervision.com/psucalculatorlite.jsp) to calculate if your PSU is sufficient enough for what you're trying to achieve. My best guesses for a standard system using the specification you've put in your question I would say it should be OK, but this was making guesses on fans and hard disks, etc - if you fill in your full system info on that website it will tell you approximately how much power is required from your PSU.

Answer (score 0):

You must use a PSU calculator and input the speific configuration of your computer and also those devices that you may add later (USB, additional cards, more RAM).

The info you have supplied is not enought to determin an exact answer to your question. If you asked, "I want to add a video card to my system and not sure if my PSU is appropriate. Where can I calculate wattage needed for additions to my computer?"

You would get an answer like this:

Here is a place to start [ASUS Computer Inc PSU calculator](http://support.asus.com/powersupply.aspx)

Enter you items, CPU type, mother board type, Ram,fans, USB/Firewire items and so on. It will calc the MIN required PSU Wattage. This will be the MINIMUM. So if after you input all you data and it comes to 450, you will need to be sure you add nothing else onto the system physiclly to exceed the wattage. In fact, it would be wise at that point to invest in a new power supply that will have more than you need.